Azure Dev Ops Email Alert Notification
In Azure Dev OPS I am looking to possible setup a notification to be sent to my business email, each time a change is made to access level.
Path: Organisational Settings > Users > Manage Access Level (Change level accordingly)
Questions: Is there a way in Azure Dev OPS, each time Access Level field is changed to Basic + Test Plans, Stakeholder etc I get an alert via to confirm a change has been made?
Looking at notification > Pull request trying to establish if the below can be done:
In Azure Dev OPS I am looking to possible setup a notification to be sent to my business email, each time a change is made to access level.
Path: Organisational Settings > Users > Manage Access Level (Change level accordingly)
Questions: Is there a way in Azure Dev OPS, each time Access Level field is changed to Basic + Test Plans, Stakeholder etc I get an alert via to confirm a change has been made?

On the Notifications settings of Azure DevOps, there is not any option to set up the subscriptions for updating the access levels of users.
The available categories for notification subscriptions are below. None of them contains the options for updating the access levels of users.

If you really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on Developer Community. This will make it more convenient for the Azure DevOps engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

